# Runepriest Game Aid?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools, runepriest

Does anyone know of any game aids for playing a runepriest. I'm not talking about a character creation or tips-n-tricks guide, but rather something I could print out for a member of my party who will be playing a runepriest from now on in the campaign. The class seems pretty complicated to run and right now my plan is for him to use pennygems as buff and debuff marks to hand to the party and the monsters (DM) for ease of tracking. I just wanted to know if other people had other solutions so I can compare and find the best one.

Comment: Honestly, the best thing for them to do is probably to come up with a flowchart/rainbow table of how they handle situations, what their default states are. While a game aid may help, doing the work to map out what your character does is probably the best bet for any character, let alone a complicated one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly common leader problem.

When I played an artificer, I printed out little "here's your buff" cards that'd literally hand to other players. The runepriest is the same way, except worse.

Runepriests are considered to be the most complex leaders in the game, and the hardest to optimize. In this situation, I'd make a double-sided card for each of my powers, likely with power2ool and a bit of ConTeXt magic. Each side would have all the numbers worked out for the specific stance I was in. (I.e. instead of cards saying up to your wisdom modifier squares, they say up to 6 squares). This way, the complexity of changing a stance would simply be "flip cards over". Beyond that, I'd have double-sided buff cards to hand out to players when they benefit from an effect.

The trick, with complicated leaders, is to make as little as possible need to be remembered. So, with buffs I hand out, it's better to replicate the "main" powers of the target player in the buff-card so that even *less* math needs to be done in real-time around the table.

In no circumstances try to get other people to remember the buffs. I've never found that that works with anything more complex than "here, bonus to hit for next attack."